# Windows Messaging

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-messages

My question is about windows messaging. I have 2 apps, communicating through WM_COPYDATA messages. Also in the first app, there are some application defined messages. The thing is, when WM_COPDATA message processed, also app defined message is send, and WM_COPYDATA processing stops and processing goes to my message. I understand it, when I add prinnt statements. (Actually, it doesn't effect program flow.)

Let me talk briefly about program flow. With every WM_COPYDATA message, one window is opened, and when it's opened a thread is created. This thread sleeps for 4 second, then sends MM_MY_MESSAGE with SendMessage(). So, at some point WM_COPYDATA and MM_MY_MESSAGE corresponds. What I expected was, after finishing one message it will continue with the next. But it happened differently.

```
case WM_COPYDATA:
    std::cout << "WM_COPYDATA started" << std::endl;
    //
    // do some stuff.
    //
    std::cout << "WM_COPYDATA finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
case MM_MY_MESSAGE:
    std::cout << "--MM_MY_MESSAGE started--" << std::endl;
    //
    // do some stuff.
    //
    std::cout << "--MM_MY_MESSAGE finished--" << std::endl;
    return 0;
```

Output is:

```
WM_COPYDATA started
WM_COPYDATA finished
WM_COPYDATA started
WM_COPYDATA finished
WM_COPYDATA started
--MM_MY_MESSAGE started--
--MM_MY_MESSAGE finished--
WM_COPYDATA finished
```

How 'MM_MY_MESSAGE' prints come between WM_COPYDATA prints?

Comment: The behavior you observe is called "reentrancy". The code helpfully represented with `do some stuff` yields - does something that "pumps" the message queue (retrieves and dispatches pending window messages). This includes, but not limited to, showing a modal dialog or a context menu; making an out-of-apartment COM call from a single-threaded apartment; and of course, calling things like `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`

Comment: Further to what @IgorTandetnik said, even calling `SendMessage` from within the message loop can cause this to happen. Without seeing the code you've omitted no one will be able to tell you exactly what's causing it.

Comment: I have added some explanation. Can't show inside case statements because it's long, some of related code is inside another thread, etc. But there are no SendMessage() calls inside case statements.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There are SetForegroundWindow() and BringWindowToTop() calls, inside WM_COPYDATA case. But parameter window is not this window (the window that processes MM_MY_MESSAGE). Can this effect my window's message loop, too? Also this window is message-only window.

Comment: Use the debugger to set a breakpoint on the `MM_MY_MESSAGE` case, and then follow the stack trace to see where the reentrancy came from.

Comment: @JonathanPotter is it possible to avoid reentrancy? Because, my code is not safe for reentrancy and sequence of these messages might be important at same situations.

Comment: The best way to avoid reentrancy is to avoid yielding. Figure out where you do that, then cease and desist.

Comment: [BringWindowToTop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673.aspx) might call `SendMessage` as part of its implementation, opening a potential for re-entrancy. `SendMessage` dispatches inbound cross-thread sent messages.